# Counting unique values in multiple rows with aggregate functions

Tags: sql, count, aggregate

Here is an example database to help illustrate the problem:
Imagine a database with the following  information

```
Color| State| Age
---------------
black neutered  3
black neutered  4
white neutered 6
white non-neutered 8
black non-neutered 4
```

I want to display the info from this database in the following way:

```
Color| Total  Count |  Total neutered  | Total Non-neutered  | Neutered Ave Age | Non-neutered Ave Age
black| 3 | 2 | 1 | 3.5 | 4
white| 2 | 1 | 1 | 8| 4
```

the statement I have written :

```
select color, 
count(color), 
SUM (case when state='neutered' then 1 else 0 end) as 'Total neutered',
SUM (case when state='non-neutered' then 1 else 0 end) as 'Total non-neutered',
'Neutered Ave Age' = case when state='neutered' then AVG(age) end,
'Non-Neutered Ave Age' = case when state='non-neutered' then AVG(age) end,
from cats
group by color, state
```

When I run these query it separates the data

```
black| 2 | 2 | 0 | 3.5 | 0
black| 1 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 4
white| 2 | 1 | 0 | 8| 0
white| 2 | 0 | 1 | 0| 4
```

Any way i cant solve this?

Comment: remove state from group by

Answer (score 0):

Presumably, you don't want `state` in the `group by` and you need to fix the `avg()`:

```
select color, count(color), 
       SUM(case when state = 'neutered' then 1 else 0 end) as TotalNeutered,
       SUM(case when state = 'non-neutered' then 1 else 0 end) as TotalnonNeutered,
       AVG(case when state = 'neutered' then age end) as NeuteredAge,
       AVG(case when state = 'non-neutered' then age end) as nonNeuteredAge
from cats
group by color;
```

It is also bad practice to put column aliases in single quotes.  Single quotes should only be used for string and date constants.

Comment: Thank you for you answer I have a follow up questions
what if I wanted to add another column that listed the range ages for each group i.e.

non-neutered age range | neutered age range
-------------------------------------------

Comment: @user2659354 . . . If you wanted the age range, you would just include conditional `min()` and `max()` expressions, similar to the `sum()` and `avg()` expressions.